# How to remove space between two columns and rows in a grid in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an application in which I have used a Grid inside which I have used a Hubtile control and showing two tiles in one row. But the output I am getting is similar to below image in which there is space between rows and columns.[image]

Can anyone please suggest,how I can remove the space between the rows and columns or it is not possible?

Also, please suggest can we show the Hubtile control in whatever way we want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `margin` attribute to change it, something like `Margin='-5'`

Comment: It would be handy when you posted the relevant code.

Comment: @venerik Please suggest after seeing the code. Thanks

Comment: @HBizhi Please suggest if where I should add Margin attribute in the above code?

Comment: @KinjanBhavsar You should add it in `xaml` file.

Comment: @HBizhi From the code, you can see that I am creating grid dynamically. I also tried to add `Margin=new Thickness(-5,-5,-5,-5)` but it doesn't  change anything. Please suggest is there any other alternative?

Comment: Share an example of your solution in a zip.